# Installing Rocketeer with Laravel 4.1, getting composer update error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

I am trying to get Rocketeer (https://github.com/Anahkiasen/rocketeer/wiki/Getting-started) set up with my Laravel 4.1 project.  Per the documentation, I added:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://github.com/changwuf31/remote"
    }
    ]
```

to the end of my composer.json file.

And in the required field, I added:

```
"illuminate/remote": "dev-master"
```

When I run this, I get:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework 4.1.x-dev
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework 4.1.x-dev
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.1.28
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.1.27
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.1.26
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.1.25
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.1.24
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.1.23
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.1.22
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.1.21
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.1.20
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.1.19
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.1.18
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.1.17
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.1.16
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.1.15
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.1.14
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.1.13
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.1.12
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.1.11
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.1.10
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.1.9
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.1.8
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.1.7
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.1.6
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.1.5
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.1.4
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.1.3
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.1.2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.1.1
    - illuminate/remote dev-master requires illuminate/support 4.2.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[4.2.x-dev], illuminate/support[4.2.x-dev].
    - illuminate/remote dev-master requires illuminate/support 4.0.x -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[4.0.x-dev], illuminate/support[4.0.x-dev, v4.0.0, v4.0.0-BETA2, v4.0.0-BETA3, v4.0.0-BETA4, v4.0.1, v4.0.10, v4.0.2, v4.0.3, v4.0.4, v4.0.5, v4.0.6, v4.0.7, v4.0.8, v4.0.9].
    - don't install illuminate/support 4.2.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v4.1.0
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v4.1.0, 4.2.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v4.1.0, 4.0.x-dev].
    - don't install illuminate/support 4.0.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v4.1.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.0.0|don't install laravel/framework v4.1.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.0.0-BETA2|don't install laravel/framework v4.1.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.0.0-BETA3|don't install laravel/framework v4.1.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.0.0-BETA4|don't install laravel/framework v4.1.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.0.1|don't install laravel/framework v4.1.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.0.10|don't install laravel/framework v4.1.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.0.2|don't install laravel/framework v4.1.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.0.3|don't install laravel/framework v4.1.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.0.4|don't install laravel/framework v4.1.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.0.5|don't install laravel/framework v4.1.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.0.6|don't install laravel/framework v4.1.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.0.7|don't install laravel/framework v4.1.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.0.8|don't install laravel/framework v4.1.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.0.9|don't install laravel/framework v4.1.0
    - Installation request for laravel/framework 4.1.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[4.1.x-dev, v4.1.0, v4.1.1, v4.1.10, v4.1.11, v4.1.12, v4.1.13, v4.1.14, v4.1.15, v4.1.16, v4.1.17, v4.1.18, v4.1.19, v4.1.2, v4.1.20, v4.1.21, v4.1.22, v4.1.23, v4.1.24, v4.1.25, v4.1.26, v4.1.27, v4.1.28, v4.1.3, v4.1.4, v4.1.5, v4.1.6, v4.1.7, v4.1.8, v4.1.9].
    - Installation request for illuminate/remote dev-master -> satisfiable by illuminate/remote[dev-master].
```

My composer.json looks like so:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "require": {
        "laravel/framework": "4.1.*",
        "way/generators": "2.*",
        "madewithlove/laravel-oauth2": "0.4.*",
        "nesbot/Carbon": "*",
        "illuminate/remote": "dev-master"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "app/commands",
            "app/controllers",
            "app/models",
            "app/libraries",
            "app/lastfmapi",
            "app/database/migrations",
            "app/database/seeds",
            "app/tests/TestCase.php",
            "app/helpers"
        ],
        "psr-0": {
          "Classes": "app/libraries"    
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://github.com/changwuf31/remote"
    }
    ]
}
```

Any ideas what is going on?

Comment: you did not read the documentation properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like you are on Laravel 4.1. The documentation on Rocketeer says this:

> **If you're on 4.1 you can skip to the next step.**

The one you are doing is the **step** to be **skipped**, that is only to be done if you are on laravel 4.0.

Remove what you previewsly did, and [do this](https://github.com/Anahkiasen/rocketeer/wiki/Getting-started#installing-rocketeer) instead:

### **Installing Rocketeer**

Now type the following to your terminal:

```
composer require anahkiasen/rocketeer:dev-master.
```

You'll need to add these lines to the `providers` array in your `app/config/app.php` file :

```
'Rocketeer\RocketeerServiceProvider',
```

Then, this line to the `aliases` array in your `app/config/app.php` file :

```
'Rocketeer' => 'Rocketeer\Facades\Rocketeer',
```

Then publish the config :

```
artisan deploy:ignite
```

And it should work.

---

Your composer json should now look somethnig like this:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "require": {
        "laravel/framework": "4.1.*",
        "way/generators": "2.*",
        "madewithlove/laravel-oauth2": "0.4.*",
        "nesbot/Carbon": "*",
        "anahkiasen/rocketeer": "dev-master"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "app/commands",
            "app/controllers",
            "app/models",
            "app/libraries",
            "app/lastfmapi",
            "app/database/migrations",
            "app/database/seeds",
            "app/tests/TestCase.php",
            "app/helpers"
        ],
        "psr-0": {
          "Classes": "app/libraries"    
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```